# Atualizar visitas ao abrir o site

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou fazendo uma função para alterar a contagem de visitas no meu site. A função é esta:

```
function visitas($conexao, $visita) {

    $query = "update visita set visitas= visitas + 1";

    return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
}
```

Porém não sei como fazer para ele contar a visita automaticamente no ato da visualização do meu site. Alguém pode me ajudar? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Se entendi bem, bastaria chamar a função. Algo como `visitas($conexao, null)` - o segundo parâmetro deixei `null` pois ele nem é necessário na função.

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson

Comment: não entendi o porque chamar uma função para contar visita automaticamente no ato da visualização. Não bastaria tão somente executar a query?

Comment: Sou leigo...rs.

Comment: tranquilo, estamos aqui para nos ajudar

Comment: Obrigado @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: Não sei se vc já viu esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Opa.. vi não... vou dar uma olhada @LeoCaracciolo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function visitas($conexao, $visita = '') {

    $query = "update visita set visitas= visitas + 1";

    return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
}

visitas($conexao);
```

Comment: O questionamento não é sobre a query e sim spbre como e em que momento chamar a função.

Comment: perdão arrumei.

Answer (score 0):

Sem muitos rodeios e voltas desnecessárias, basta executar a query:

```
$query = "update visita set visitas= visitas + 1"; 
$data = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
```